# Extract all error validation messages from a webpage, javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, reactjs, validation

Almost every web based application embeds the validation logic for its fields within the page, mostly in the form of Javascript. I am trying to extract all the error validation messages that exist in the Javascript, webpage.

Example of error validation fields for password field would be:

1. Password cannot be empty.
2. Password cannot be <= 8 characters
3. Password cannot be >= 15 characters
4. Password should have an uppercase letter.

I get it that the messages and their number would be dependent on the developer/functionality/front-end technology of the app. I just need to extract all the available validation messages if there are any.

Is there a way this can be accomplished? Will appreciate any pointers on the same.